# error while importing tex file to lyx

Tags: lyx

i'm getting this error message

An error occurred while running:
`/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/MacOS/tex2lyx" -f "nrcd.tex" "nrcd.lyx`

while importing tex file to lyx 2.0.6
can anyone help please?

Comment: Is this a Mac-reported error, or a LyX-reported error? It the latter, then it may help posting the LyX file (perhaps on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com), if too large).

Answer (score 7):

This is an error reported by LyX (actually `tex2lyx` which is a separate program). LyX cannot be expected to import every `.tex` file (because LyX is not a LaTeX editor, it has it's own format it needs to convert to and parsing LaTeX can be very difficult). If you can reduce your `.tex` file to a minimal example, please post it as an [enhancement request](http://www.lyx.org/trac) and for the component choose `tex2lyx`. Also note that `tex2lyx` is improving in every release, so there's a chance that you would be able to import with [LyX 2.1 beta 1](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.1/lyx-2.1.0beta1).

Note that LyX cannot even be expected to import files that it exports. This may seem silly to many, but it is an extremely difficult problem to solve. The reason is simply that importing (involves parsing) is not a straightforward inverse of exporting (involves writing). They are implemented in completely different ways. In fact, in LyX they are completely separate programs. `lyx` actually calls the program `tex2lyx` to import.

Whenever you export in any program, you should expect to lose data and you should not expect to be able to go backwards. With save, you do not lose data. This is why some programs, such as LyX, decide to keep the "export" and "save" operations separate instead of combining them.