# cannot import tex file into LyX

Tags: lyx

I have installed the LaTeX class files for Springer `svjour3` as instructed at http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Springer

But I cannot import `template.tex` into LyX (using plain latex option). The error comes out:

> "cannot convert file- an error occured while running tex2lyx -f
>   template.tex template.lyx"

Next I tried to create a new file from template provided by LyX, `svjour3.lyx`.
No problem here, I can view the PDF. Then I exported it to a `.tex` file (using plain LaTeX option) and tried importing it back again to LyX. The cannot convert error above appears.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Have you read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72780) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135551)?

Comment: Why would you export to `.tex` format and then try to import the file back to LyX?

Comment: It shows that LyX is problematic with Springer class files. It can't even import a .tex file it generated. Does anyone have the same experience? There are some differences in the .tex file generated by LyX compared to the template provided by Springer. I am not sure if this will be a problem later on with submission?

Comment: LyX is strong in some areas and weak in others. It is good at generating LaTeX, but very poor at importing from it (which in fairness is a very difficult problem). Even LyX's developers admit this. You could report this to the LyX developers because it is a bug, but it is not really a surprise that it's possible to write LyX files that do not survive a round trip via LaTeX.

Comment: @JimOldfield good points, although in my opinion this is not a "bug" but rather a "feature request".

Comment: In my opinion this is a duplicate. It could be regarded as its own question if the title is changed to "why can't LyX import files that it exports" as the other question did not have that detail. However, I edited the answer to add that detail.

Comment: Note for archival purposes that this question was cross-posted at http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=24955&sid=bacef44f40a327dbc8912bd29671edfa